# Cannot find path cause of weird path name

Tags: powershell

I have a path that looks like this:

```
$path = path\to\weird\filename\PUBLISERET - Dalager 1, Brøndby - Leveringsaftale D12-24311 1.0.pdf
```

When I do:

```
Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $path -Name IsReadOnly -Value $true
```

I tells me that the path doesn't exist even though it does. I believe it is because of the file name. What can I do?

Comment: Are you missing quotes in the `$path` assignment? If you aren't, that's the problem. If you are, please edit the question and add the details. A literal error message would be of use.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting single quotes around the path.

```
$path = 'path\to\weird\filename\PUBLISERET - Dalager 1, Brøndby - Leveringsaftale D12-24311 1.0.pdf'
```

Comment: @BenjaminS.Sorterup You really should include the error message in the question. Without it, it's all guesswork.

Comment: I can do an Get-ChildItem on the directory and see the file but when I do Set-ItemProperty on that specific file it does this error:
`Set-ItemProperty : Cannot find path $path because it does not exist.`

Answer (score 1):

[Dmitriy Kapitanov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39952738/3439404) is right: put single quotes around the path. **Proof**:

```
PS D:\PShell> $path = 'D:\bat\Unusual Names\Türkçe (Türkiye)\PUBLISERET - Dalager 1, Brøndby - Leveringsaftale D12-24311 1.0.pdf'
PS D:\PShell> Get-ItemProperty $path


    Directory: D:\bat\Unusual Names\Türkçe (Türkiye)


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        31.08.2015     17:55      34429 PUBLISERET - Dalager 1, Brøndby - Leveringsaftale
                                             D12-24311 1.0.pdf


PS D:\PShell> Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $path -Name IsReadOnly -Value $true
PS D:\PShell> Get-ItemProperty $path


    Directory: D:\bat\Unusual Names\Türkçe (Türkiye)


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-ar--        31.08.2015     17:55      34429 PUBLISERET - Dalager 1, Brøndby - Leveringsaftale
                                             D12-24311 1.0.pdf


PS D:\PShell>
```